# How to add slimscroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slimscroll

So I am trying to add slimscroll to my table for my live chatbox, but what ever I do nothing works. The source I'm providing you does not include any attempt of my adding it as there's no point of me just pointing out my failures.

Chatbox.php

```
   <?php include_once("@header/header.php"); ?>
<div class="wraper container-fluid">
<div class="page-title"> </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2>Shoutbox <small>Support is not provided here; open a ticket. <strong>NO ADVERTISING, NO SPAMMING</strong></small></h2>
                <?php
                    $viewUsers = $odb->prepare("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
                    $viewUsers->execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username']));
                    $rank = $viewUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if($rank['rank'] == 1) {
                    ?>
                <div class="panel-actions">
                    <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearchat()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Clear</button>
                </div>
                <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
            <div id="logs" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 450px;">
                <table id="chatlogs" class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message here..">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" id="send" onclick="send()" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button></span>
                    <input type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include_once("@header/footer.php"); ?>
<script>
    function clearchat() {

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "@ajax/clearchat.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<script>
    function send() {
      var message=$('#message').val();
      var username=$('#username').val();

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "@ajax/sendmessage.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("message=" + message + "&username=" + username);

      $('#message').val('');
    }
</script>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    $('#chatlogs').load("@ajax/shoutbox.php").fadeIn("slow");
       setInterval("updateContent();", 1000 ); 
       function updateContent() 
        { 
             $('#chatlogs').load("@ajax/shoutbox.php").fadeIn("slow"); 
        } 
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#message').keypress(function(e){
          if(e.keyCode==13)
          $('#send').click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does `div with id logs` contains chatbox?

Answer (score 0):

i made this CSS and its work with me...
you can change the width as you want..

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 3px;   /*for vertical scrollbars*/ 
    height: 12px;  /*for horizontal scrollbars*/ 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: #818B99;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-background-clip: content-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `overflow` property for `div` with `id` `logs` to `scroll`

```
<div id="logs" style="overflow: scroll; width: auto; height: 450px;">
```

If you just need vertical scroll and no horizontal ones.

```
<div id="logs" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; width: auto; height: 450px;">
```

For fancier scrolls like slimmer ones try using different plugins available for scrolls and checkout its implementations. There are multiple questions on SO for slimscrolls with different possible options for an answer. And they are easier to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old, but it seems like, from the question, that you want to use slimscroll, but dont have a reference in the code.

To use jquery slimscroll you need to add a reference first like:

```
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
```

(or where you have your plugin).

Then you may add the slimscroll to your table like:

```
 // Add slimscroll to table
          $('#chatlogs').slimscroll({
              height : '400px'
          });
```